# Artifactory Plugin build.name concatenates with +-+ syntax

Tags: artifactory

When using the Aritfactory plug in for Bamboo with spec files the `build.name` is being concatenated with `+-+` on the `PUT`. This causes a 404. I have replicated this using curl and the same can be seen. If I take out the `+-+` in the manual curl, everything works fine.

e.g. this is the put that is generated:

```
PUT https://our-url.com/artifactory/generic-repo-local/base-artifacts/ansible/ansible_archive.tgz;
vcs.revision=somerevisionstring;
build.timestamp=1525095244921;
build.name=test;
build.name=AWS_CheckPoint_Management+-+BUILD_CONFIG_MANAGEMENT_DRAFT+-+Push_To_Artifactory;
build.number=22;
```

A 404 is returned from Artifactory. If I take out the `build.name` in curl from the same build agent, it all works fine.